# Track changes in a table on a daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp

I have a table that stores each of our properties and whether they have certain icons against them on the website. This table is updated on a daily basis and date stamped.

Table Fields:

- DateStamp,
- PropertyCode,
- PropertyName,
- FacilityBabyFriendly,
- FacilityDogsAccepted,
- FacilitySwimmingPool,
- FacilityHotTub,
  FacilityInternetAccess,
- FacilitySeaViews,
- FacilityParking

All the Facility fields are stored as a 1 [has icon] or 0 [no icon]

What I need is query that shows me, by property, if any of the facility fields have changed on a daily basis.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, if would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I should have said, it's MS SQL.

Comment: also, what are the data types of the FacilityX rows?

Comment: If you are using MS SQL you have audit features included as from 2008 version. With it you can track all changes and access to your database objects. [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx)

Comment: The data types are int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you the list of properties which has atleast one of the facility fields changed as compared with the previous day

```
SELECT 
     PropertyCode
    ,PropertyName
FROM Souce s1
WHERE 
    DateStamp = Current_Date
    AND 
    EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
        FROM 
    Source s2
    WHERE 
        s1.PropertyCode=s2.PropertyCode
        AND DateStamp = Current_Date - 1 Day
        AND 
        (
        (s1.FacilityBabyFriendly<>s2.FacilityBabyFriendly)
        OR 
        (s1.FacilityDogsAccepted<>s2.FacilityDogsAccepted)
        OR
        (s1.FacilitySwimmingPool<>s2.FacilitySwimmingPool)
        OR 
        (s1.FacilityHotTub<>s2.FacilityHotTub)
        OR 
        (s1.FacilityInternetAccess<>s2.FacilityInternetAccess)
        OR 
        (s1.FacilitySeaViews<>s2.FacilitySeaViews)
        OR 
        (s1.FacilityParking<>s2.FacilityParking)
        )
    )
```

Comment: Perfect. Works exactly as I wanted . Many Thanks Claire

Comment: @Claire: Happy to help. upvote if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 0):

once thing you can do is calculate the hash of each row to compare if there is any change:

```
select hashbytes('MD5',cast(FacilityBabyFriendly * 1000000 + FacilityDogsAccepted * 100000 + FacilitySwimmingPool * 10000 + FacilityHotTub * 1000 + FacilityInternetAccess * 100 + FacilitySeaViews * 10 + FacilityParking
as varchar(100) )
) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Value <> 0 means facility has changed

```
SELECT DateStamp
      ,PropertyCode
      ,PropertyName
      ,FacilityBabyFriendly - LAG(FacilityBabyFriendly) OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyCode, PropertyName ORDER BY DateStamp) AS FacilityBabyFriendlyChanged
      ,FacilityDogsAccepted - LAG(FacilityDogsAccepted) OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyCode, PropertyName ORDER BY DateStamp) AS FacilityDogsAcceptedChanged
      ,FacilitySwimmingPool - LAG(FacilitySwimmingPool) OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyCode, PropertyName ORDER BY DateStamp) AS FacilitySwimmingPoolChanged
      ,FacilityHotTub - LAG(FacilityHotTub) OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyCode, PropertyName ORDER BY DateStamp) AS FacilityHotTubChanged
      ,FacilityInternetAccess - LAG(FacilityInternetAccess) OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyCode, PropertyName ORDER BY DateStamp) AS FacilityInternetAccessChanged
      ,FacilitySeaViews - LAG(FacilitySeaViews) OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyCode, PropertyName ORDER BY DateStamp) AS FacilitySeaViewsChanged
      ,FacilityParking - LAG(FacilityParking) OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyCode, PropertyName ORDER BY DateStamp) AS FacilityParkingChanged
FROM YourTable
```